# PostgreSQL keeps asking for user password with "trust" authentication enabled

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I created a user `john` with `createuser` and didn't supply any passwords for it, i.e. no `-P` option specified. I then proceeded to add the following line **above** all other lines in the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
host    all             john            127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

I then restarted the server but even after that, when I try to run `psql -U john` it keeps asking for a password. I even ran the command `psql -c "alter role john with password null;"` but it changed nothing. PostgreSQL keeps asking for a password for `john`. What am I missing?

Running PostgreSQL 13.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking the logs, it got apparent that PostgreSQL was matching the `::1/128` IPv6 address, which had `scram-sha-256` as its authentication method. adding a line like

```
host    all             john            ::1/128            trust
```

fixed the problem.

Also, there is no need for restarting the DBMS after changes to `pg_hba.conf`.